# Trigger an event on a shadow DOM element that is overlaid by an element in the light DOM (not a parent)

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener, shadow-dom

I am trying to get the coordinates of a shadow DOM table cell that may (or may-not) have overlay elements displayed in front of it. The clickable overlay elements may span over multiple cells so they will not necessarily be children of the cell I need the coordinates from.

I can't get the event to bubble through the table like I expect. I believe event re-targeting of the shadow DOM is preventing the event from ever hitting the cells when the event originates in the light DOM (*I kinda think that this is the wrong approach anyways as the overlay element is not a child of the cell I want the coordinates from to begin with*)

The "pointer-events: none;"property pretty much does what I want, however, I need the event to also trigger on the light DOM overlay element so I don't know if that is an option.

I am thinking it is a good idea to avoid attaching a listener to every cell for performance issues (in the final application there will be hundreds of cells)

I am using vanilla JavaScript

In the provided example, is it possible to get the correct coordinates of the underlying table cell when the overlying div grey is clicked?

```js
class Custom_Grid extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
          td {
            height:50px; width:50px; border: 1px solid grey;            
          }
        </style>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td id='x0y0'><slot name='x0y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x0y1'><slot name='x0y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x0y2'><slot name='x0y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='x1y0'><slot name='x1y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x1y1'><slot name='x1y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x1y2'><slot name='x1y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='x2y0'><slot name='x2y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x2y1'><slot name='x2y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x2y2'><slot name='x2y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        
      `;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches('td'))
        console.log(`Grid Cell: ${e.target.id}`)
    });
  }

}

window.customElements.define('custom-grid', Custom_Grid);


document.getElementById('grid_overlay').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("#overGrid Click")
});
```

```css
#grid_overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  /*pointer-events: none; <-- not an option?*/
}
```

```html
<custom-grid>
  <div slot='x1y0' id='grid_overlay'></div>
</custom-grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to hide the overlay element temporarily in order to get the covered element thanks to the [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) method.

```
if ( e.target.id === 'grid_overlay' ) {        
   console.log( 'overlay click' )
   e.target.hidden = true 
   var el = this.shadowRoot.elementFromPoint( e.x, e.y )
   if (el.id)
     console.log( 'under: ', el.id )
   e.target.hidden = false
}
```

```js
class Custom_Grid extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
          td {
            height:50px; width:50px; border: 1px solid grey;            
          }
        </style>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td id='x0y0'><slot name='x0y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x0y1'><slot name='x0y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x0y2'><slot name='x0y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='x1y0'><slot name='x1y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x1y1'><slot name='x1y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x1y2'><slot name='x1y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='x2y0'><slot name='x2y0'></slot></td>
        <td id='x2y1'><slot name='x2y1'></slot></td>
        <td id='x2y2'><slot name='x2y2'></slot></td>
        </tr>
        
      `;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches('td'))
        console.log(`Grid Cell: ${e.target.id}`)
      else if (e.target.id === 'grid_overlay' ) {        
        console.log( 'overlay click ' )
        e.target.hidden = true 
        var el = this.shadowRoot.elementFromPoint( e.x, e.y )
        if (el.id)
          console.log( 'under: ', el.id )
        e.target.hidden = false
      }
    });
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-grid', Custom_Grid);
```

```css
#grid_overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<custom-grid>
  <div slot='x1y0' id='grid_overlay'></div>
</custom-grid>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. If by chance anyone out there is trying to do this with an overlay that is another custom element, you need to add a :host display style that respects the hidden attribute (or else it the hidden attribute is overridden).